# How to invoke the print dialog of a reportviewer control in a content page?

Tags: javascript

Here is the java script I use to invoke the print dialog of a ReportViewer control:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
         function PrintReport() { 
             var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

             var stillonLoadState = clientViewer.get_isLoading();

             if (!stillonLoadState ) { 
                 var reportArea = viewerReference .get_reportAreaContentType(); 
                 if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) { 
                     $find("ReportViewer1").invokePrintDialog(); 
                 } 
             } 
         } 
     </script>
```

But it cannot find the reportviewer control, it says: "Unable to get property 'get_isLoading' of undefined or null reference".

If I use a webforms it Works, but if I use a content page, with a main and a secondary master page, then it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post all of your code

Comment: Doco for Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd756405(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a temporarily solution by searching for the reportviewer ID in the source code in the browser, not the best solution, but it worked.

Thanks